# Run script with root permission as normal user

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, chown

## Problem:

How can I run a script owned by root with root permission as normal user?

Let's take for example a folder `/path/to/folder`.
First I make sure that the folder and all content is owned by root:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /path/to/folder
```

Then I tried different approaches of giving permissions to other users:

```
sudo chmod -R +x /path/to/folder
sudo chmod -R u+s /path/to/folder
sudo chmod -R 4755 /path/to/folder
```

But the script I want to run, still gives me:

```
Can't open /dev/mem: Permission denied
```

---

## Detailed

I have a Flask application which changes colours of an led-strip according to incoming requests.

Regardless of which library is used, accessing GPIO always needs root permission.

I would like to change this for two reasons:

- I am using venv and running the app with `sudo` causes the globally installed python packaged to be used rather than the ones in venv.
- In its finished state the application should run in apache. So far I didn't get apache to run the app with sudo.

---

I would like to focus on the main problem, rather than Flask or the led-strip library.

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

I looked into the suggested question and my user is in the gpio group, the `dev/gpiomem` folder exists and has the exact same permissions and still I get the `/dev/mem` permission denied error.

Now I found out, that the package I am using apparently uses `/dev/mem` exclusively and doesn't support `/dev/gpiomem`.
(https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x)

I'm now looking for an alternative and I am open for suggestions :-)

Comment: Instead, maybe [check this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40105). Nothing says you have to have root rights. // Using the setuid bit still makes the script run as root (except scripts cannot use setuid). I suggest you read up a little on Linux and chmod and whatnot.

Comment: [You should never ever set the SUID bit on a script](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=30) As Daniel pointed out you can allow your normal user to access GPIO just fine.

Comment: Thanks, to both of you - actually I already found the question but I didn't get it to work. I will take a closer look. And even though setting the suid bit is not recommended, I am interested what I missed. The owner is root, the executable and suid bit are set and still when I run my python gpio script I get the dev/mem permission denied error. Also tried this with a bash script and whoami -> echoes pi. Its a bit frustrating, every solution I found is either not working or not recommended...

Comment: I updated my question, seems like the package I am using doesn't supports /dev/gpiomem

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314858/10765659)?

Comment: I actually now found a way to get the used package to work with /dev/gpiomem and I can run it without sudo. Now the problem is, that setting the led colors doesn't work like before ... if there's no solution, I will go back to using setuid and take a closer look - thank you!

Comment: The mentioned solution resulted in new problems which I can't seem to solve because there is no documentation ...

I no tried to do it with the SUID bit again, but apparently it has no effect for non-binaries in unix shells.